# var foo = (function(){...})(); ... foo() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, syntax

as expected it invokes the function foo the first time, but when i want to use the function another time the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'foo' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

the intention was to define a function (which has to be called immediately, but also later on) - do i have to write the following instead:

```
function foo() {...}
foo();
... // later on
foo();
```

or is there a more elegant solution?

EDIT: if you cannot use a variable (even if it's an anonymous function) as a function, what is its advantage anyway?

(why does

```
var foo = (function(){...})();
... // later on
foo();
```

not work?)

Comment: What is "later on"? Later in the same block of script, or in a different block of script?

Comment: What do you want to happen? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: What you have here is a typical example of a non-problem. Just call it and forget it and get back to creating awesome websites! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand

```
var foo = (function(){...})();
foo();
```

you will get this:

```
function temp() {
    ...
}
foo = temp();
```

As you can see, you are calling the temp function (bolded here): `var foo = (function(){...})`**`()`**`;`. This means that `foo` is not being assigned to a function object, but the return value of that function call. Therefore, unless the temporary function returns a function (and in that case you might want to consider refactoring), the value stored in `foo` will not be callable.

In JavaScript, there are two ways to store a function object:

**A)** Pass a function without calling it (i.e. `foo = bar;` instead of `foo = bar()`).

**B)** *(If you need to pass parameters)* pass a function call wrapped in another function (without calling the wrapper function) (i.e. `foo = function {bar(param1, param2);};` instead of `foo = function {bar(param1, param2);}();` *(notice the **`()`** at the end? -- you don't want that)*).

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you assign the result of calling the anonymous function to `foo`, instead of the function itself.

When you then try to call `foo()`, you are trying to treat the result of the first function call (apparently of type `DOMWindow`) as a function, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var foo;
(foo = function(){...})();
```

but this is not well-readable.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
var foo = function()  { ..... }
```

instead of

```
var foo = (function() { .. } ) ();
```

in your case you are assigning a anonymous function to foo.